# Fragment disappears whenever it goes to its onPause() and the ui returns to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Basically i have 3 activities, activity 1 = ChooserActivity, activity 2 = SignInActivity, activity 3 = HomeActivity. Starting activity will decided on weather user is logged in or not. In this case user is loggeg in and HomeActivity is started which contain navigation drawer, when user click on any item it start a fragment and when this fragment goes to it's onPause ...UI return me to HomeActivity instead of showing me the fragment.
Here is the code for HomeActivity!

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (id == R.id.nav_add_donor) {
        fragment = new AddDonorFragment();
    }else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
    }

    if(fragment!=null) {

        ft.replace(R.id.content_home, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: u are assigning too many operations on the navigation method. Try constructing the fragment on the onCreate method of the class. Keep only the necessary code inside the navigationItemSelect

Comment: That's not the issue i think, if i'm not wrong